# Using a dropdown list to sort by dataset in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am building an Audit History report for my companies application, but due to the requirements I have been given, I need to use multiple datasets.  Is there a way to make a dropdown list that requires a selection to be made before the query is run, and that allows me to tie each selection to a different dataset?

For example, I have 4 entities (Account, Contact, Opportunity, and), each tied to a different data set. I want the dropdown to be required in order for the query to be run, and I want it to include each of the four entities as selections, and each selection should be tied to the respective dataset for that entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are showing different `subreports` or `tablix` for each dataset and setting it's visibility depending on `parameter` selected. Because you can not bind the multiple `datasets`  to the single `tablix`. So you have to do that first then for your query to how to fire conditional dataset on user selection. `SSRS` always firs up all the queries from its all available datasets. But you can reduce the time of result returning bu using the following way,

Include an `AND :ParameterName = 'Y'` condition in the `where` clause - if your parameter is not `'Y'`, the query will still fire, but it will immediately return 0 records.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up figuring out a way to adapt my query to fulfill my requirements.  But your response is very helpful.